# Puedo hacer que una función solo exista si pulso un check

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hola estoy haciendo los metodos de pago, y pueden elegir entre Stripe y Paypal. Para los dos gasto el mismo formulario, y según el check que elija me cambia la ruta del form. Hasta ahí voy bien, el problema es que Stripe se construye así:

```
<div id="strypePay" style="display: none;">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name_on_card">Name on Card</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_on_card" name="name_on_card">
      </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="card-element">Credit Card</label>
       <div id="card-element">
        <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
       </div>
    
       <!-- Used to display form errors -->
       <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
```

Es por que en Stripe hay que poner el número de la tarjeta, entonces yo he hecho que cuando este paypal marcado esto este oculto y si marco stripe se muestra.

Luego la función de Stripe es la siguiente:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    // Create a Stripe client
    var stripe = Stripe('{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}');
    // Create an instance of Elements
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        fontFamily: '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };
    // Create an instance of the card Element
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        style: style,
        hidePostalCode: true
    });
    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
    card.mount('#card-element');
    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });
    // Handle form submission
    var form = document.getElementById('confirmar_pedido');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var options = {
        name: document.getElementById('name_on_card').value,
      }
      stripe.createToken(card, options).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          // Send the token to your server
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
      });
    });
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('confirmar_pedido');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
})();
</script>
```

Y yo oculto y muestro el contenido de la tarjeta en stripe del siguiente modo:

```
$('#paypal').click(function(){
    $('#confirmar_pedido').attr('action', '{{ route('PaymentController.pay') }}');
    $('#strypePay').css("display","none");
  });
  $('#stripe').click(function(){
    $('#confirmar_pedido').attr('action', '{{ route('stripe.pay') }}');
    $('#strypePay').css("display","block");
  });
```

Entonces cuando click en paypal, hay modo de desactivar la función de Stripe?? es que si no, no envia el formulario por que poner la tarjeta es requerido.

**Idea:**

Habia pensado, en el Stripe en lugar de llevar una id Form llevara una clase css, así si pulso paypal elimino la clase css del form, pero no funciona, no reconoce el formulario:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.addEventListener is not a function
```

He cambiado estas lineas

```
var form = document.getElementById('confirmar_pedido');
var form = document.getElementById('confirmar_pedido');
```

Poniendo esto: `document.getElementsByClassName('prueba');`

**Estoy probando así**

```
$('#confirmar_pedido input').on('change', function() {
    var selection = ($('input[name=metodoPago]:checked', '#confirmar_pedido').val()); 
    if(selection == 'stripe'){
      funcionStripe()
    }else{

    }
 });
```

Cuando recibo el valor stripe, carga la función. Pero el problema es que si de stripe paso a paypal que es otro input radio sigue funcionando esa función

Comment: La función de stripe es una función auto invocada, por lo que siempre se va a ejecutar, puedes revisar [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), podrías intentar sacar todo el cuerpo de la función a otra que no sea auto invocada e intentar llamarla cuando lo necesites

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta @Jorius podrias ayudarme por favor??, no se muy bien como hacer lo que me dices

Comment: Al final de mi click function le he puesto esto `funcionStripe();` Y la función de el Stripe por defecto autoinvocada, le he llamado así `function funcionStripe(){` como lo primero que me cargas es el paypal y stripe es otra opción, funciona bien, pero si selecciono stripe y luego paypal de nuevo ya no se ejecuta @Jorius

Comment: Podrías habilitar o deshabilitar los campos requeridos por Stripe de acuerdo al método de pago elegido; si no sabes cuáles son, usa el inspector del navegador.

Comment: Hola @Triby he utilizado el inspector de elemento, pero lo que carga es un iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al cambiar de PayPal a Stripe podrías quitar el evento "submit" que agregaste al cambiar a "Stripe", pero también podrías simplificarlo almacenando qué opción has seleccionado:

```
let eleccion = 'paypal';
$('#paypal').click(function(){
    eleccion = 'paypal';
    $('#confirmar_pedido').attr('action', '{{ route('PaymentController.pay') }}');
    $('#strypePay').css("display","none");
});
$('#stripe').click(function(){
    eleccion = 'stripe';
    $('#confirmar_pedido').attr('action', '{{ route('stripe.pay') }}');
    $('#strypePay').css("display","block");
});
```

De este modo podrás cancelar la ejecución del evento que te impide el envío del formulario en caso de que hayas vuelto a marcar PayPal:

```
var form = document.getElementById('confirmar_pedido');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  /* Si volvimos a marcar otra opción, cancelamos la ejecución de este código */
  if (eleccion !== 'stripe') {
     return;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  var options = {
    name: document.getElementById('name_on_card').value,
  }
  stripe.createToken(card, options).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @OscarGarcia funciona perfectamente!